# Inversion of a sequence of a number (stack and queue)

Tags: java, stack, queue

I'm curious: why does a stack invert a sequence of numbers, but a queue will not? Thank you!

Comment: The [`Stack` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is almost certainly what you need to read, specifically *A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class*.

Comment: Because ... a stack is "last in first out" (LIFO) and a queue is "first in first out" (FIFO).  It is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stack adds at the front and removes from the front (Last In, First Out). So if you add the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to a stack and then remove them, you get 3, 2, 1.

A queue adds at the end and pulls from the front (First In, First Out). So if you add the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to a queue and then remove them, you get 1, 2, 3.

Think of a stack as a stack of paper on your desk. You get the first piece of paper and place it on your desk. The next piece of paper comes in, and you place it on top of the first piece. As each subsequent piece of paper comes in, you place it on the top of the stack. The last item you added is always on the top. So when you start taking them from the top.

A queue is like the line at the ATM. You walk up and there are a dozen people in line. You go to the back of the line, and wait your turn. Customers are served in the order in which they arrived.